# Can Rikulo stream use optionnal route segments?

Tags: dart, rikulo

With Rikulo's `StreamServer`, is it possible to specify a route with optionnal segments ?
For example, I tried to build this route pattern:

```
/default/(controller:\w+)/(action:\w+)(/(id:\w+))?
```

For matching both `/default/user/get` and `/default/user/get/myId`.
In fact, this route correctly matches these 2 URLs, but when I try to get the id value with `connect.dataset['id']`, it's always `null` :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by the nested grouping which is not handled well in 0.7.4. Before it was fixed, you can use the following instead:

```
r"/default/(controller:\w+)/(action:\w+)/(id:\w+)?": yourHandler,
r"/default/(controller:\w+)/(action:\w+)": yourHandler
```

I posted the issue [here](https://github.com/rikulo/stream/issues/38).

> Update: It has been fixed in 0.7.5. Please upgrade to the latest version.